# How to replace ReadLine to exit my app?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm feeling so dumb to ask this but..
How can I prevent my app from exiting without blocking the thread?

Currently it is a console application. But it will be a "windows-app" 
(right click in VS on the startup project -> app -> output type: (first) windows app - not a store app. This is just to have an "invisible" app without any kind of GUI. So I can't use `Console.ReadLine()` later)

What I'm currently doing

```
var app = WebApp.Start<OwinStartup>(url);
Console.ReadLine(); // wait until I press enter
app.Dispose();
```

I don't want to block my thread like this

```
while (isRunning)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

What possibilities do I have to achieve this?

Comment: It completely depends on what "an event" is. Clarifying it may make the question easier to answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've tried so simplify it - hope this make things more clear

Answer (score 3):

So a disclaimer, I am not familiar with `WebApp` at all. However, you could use a `ManualResetEvent` to accomplish what you want.

```
using (var app = WebApp.Start<OwinStartup>(url))
{
      ManualResetEvent stopHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);//Might need to be true, I always get this mixed up.
      //Pass handle to app somehow
      stopHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

So this code creates the app and then creates a `ManualResetEvent`. This event is then passed to the app and then the thread stops and waits for it to be set. Inside the app you can set it whenever you want, you can read console input, wait for a button on a page to be clicked or whatever.

I am assuming here that the `WebApp` class handles creating another thread or uses async to handle web requests. Otherwise you would need to run the app on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly you are looking for something like below.

```
Dispatcher.Run();
```

the above piece of code will keep the thread/app active and wait for message on the `Dispatcher` as long as shutdown has not been requested on that particular  `Dispatcher`.

 Not for a console project you need to add reference to `WindowsBase`

You can then decide to shutdown the application from another thread.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var waitThread = new Thread(Dispatcher.Run) {IsBackground = false};
        waitThread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Application is still running");
       //to exit application shutdown waitThread here
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -2):

You can do an asynchronous application wait using the `async` and `await` tag. And this is assuming you have .NET 4.5 as your framework.

```
private static bool hasExitedApp; // flag to be used for exiting
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Application is running...");
    performAsynchronousWait();
    Console.WriteLine("Application is still running...");
    // do other processes here
}

private async static void performAsynchronousWait()
{
    while (!hasExitedApp)
        await Task.Delay(100); // Task.Delay uses a timer, so there's no blocking the UI

    Console.WriteLine("Has excited the application...");
    // do shutdown processes here
}
```

I used console here to show that the execution of main will still continue, but the method `performAsynchronousWait` is still executing. You're UI thread will continue but a background process will still happen.

Comment: This won't work. Main will exit immediately. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `Main` will exit because after `Main` execution the console closes, but he specifically said he'd use it as a `windows-app` where that behavior doesnt exists. So the TO's real problem is **how not to block the UI thread**. I used console as an example, because this will show that the thread does continue and the awaiter is still executing.

Answer (score -2):

A very simplistic approach will be to display a MessageBox with OK button only. This will block the execution until the user has clicked the button or simply pressed "Enter" key. This I think resembles the behavior of the "Console.ReadLine()" provided you don't actually expect any input at this stage.